# Loading Batch Parameters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, batch

I usually work my batches in Excel and then copy/paste it into ArcGIS batch UI.

Is it possible to do the same in QGIS? I want to be able to automatically fill the batch inputs with the information in my excel sheet.

The tutorials I've seen show how to fill the interface line by line, only.  I'm using QGIS 2.8.2. (I can use a more advanced version if needed).

Comment: What does one or two rows (with just a few key fields like lat/long, ID, etc) in your Excel file look like?  What are the precise and detailed steps that you have performed to try and get the Excel file you show into QGIS?